# BlockingQueue design with multiple monitors

Tags: java, synchronization, blocking, monitor, java.util.concurrent

I am writing a BlockingQueue and am wondering how other implementations solve this problem:

If I only have one monitor (the queue object) and let producers and consumers `wait`, I will have to ensure that `notifyAll` instead of `notify` is called, otherwise a producer might only signal another waiting producer to continue even if the queue is full. Making the consumer wait even though stuff is available. On the other hand calling `notifyAll` doesn't seem to be a scalable solution for many threads and processors.

Do `BlockingQueue`s use two monitors? One were the producers wait and one were the consumers wait? Then I would have to synchronize the the queue and the relavant monitor in a encapsulated manner. Is that the way to go?

Comment: I assume you already had a look at the implementations of blocking queues in [Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)?

Comment: Thanks, no, were can I see it?

Comment: Download and install any Java SDK >= 5.0 and find the file "src.zip" which contains the source code to the standard Java API. If using eclipse, you may want to attach this file as "source file" to the "rt.jar" library for easy navigation and access to the sources and JavaDoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how it's done in `BlockingQueue`, but one possible solution is to use [`ReentrantLock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) instead of `synchronized`.

It has the same semantics as `syncrhonized`, but provides some improvements. In particular, it can have several conditions other threads can `wait` on:

```
public class MyBlockingQueue<E> {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();

    public void put(E e) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (isFull()) notFull.await();
            boolean wasEmpty = isEmpty();
            ...
            if (wasEmpty) notEmpty.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public E take() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (isEmpty()) notEmpty.await();
            boolean wasFull = isFull();
            ...
            if (wasFull) notFull.signal();
            ...
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I was just checking the LinkedBlockingQueue and it uses the same technique but with two locks (put and take). Is this a performance booster, or why have they got two locks?

Comment: @Franz: Yes, they use some optimization with two locks, as described in comments. `ArrayBlockingQueue`, however, uses a single lock exactly as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using `notifyAll()` is the better approach compared to `notify()`. As you mentioned you could use two monitor objects, one for read and one for write access.
Using `notify()` instead can be error prone and the performance penalty for using `notifyAll()` is in most cases neglectable and usually does not require different coding since each thread waiting has to be prepared for *spurious wakeups* anyway.